# Ubuntu desktop will not start with startx

Tags: 14.04, server, .desktop

My system SSD crashed and burned (literally) and I've replaced it.  I've been able to make a new install of 14.04 server and then installed the stripped down ubuntu-desktop.  Before the crash I had a stripped down version of Gnome.  I restored my home directory and (as expected) have problems:  after I enter startx I have a background and a few desktop folders but nothing else.  No launcher, control-alt-t, nor anything else works.

There are some hidden gnome folders and files in my home folder.

How can I recover from this?

Some ~/.xsession-errors none of which give me any hints as I'm not knowledgeable about X Windows.

```
libGL error: failed to open DRM device: Permission denied.
No module named gconf
bluez.vala:104 GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdaptor
inictl: UStART_SESSION isn't set in the environment: Unable to locate the Upstart instance.
... and many more ...
```

Comment: If "stripped down" is not essential, I suggest that you run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, reboot, and try again.

Comment: I've tried that with the --no-install-recommends flag, no joy!

Comment: Any hints in `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: It's critical that I get some window system working today.  Should I remove ubuntu-desktop and attempt to reinstall a minimal Gnome?  or ??

Comment: Those messages in `~/.xsession-errors` are certainly not normal. Unfortunately I'm not knowledgable enough to interpret them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit grub:

GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"

Apparently the video drivers for my video won't work if added to the kernel by default.
Many thanks to a NASA colleague from the past who manages some Ubuntu systems for a living.